# How can i create a remote connection?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to use .mdf file of my database but as  i select it in Entity Data Model Wizard It warns me to create a Remote connection (Error 26 SqlServer2008). i read different articles and followed their guidelines but still error has not removed.my Operating System is Windows xp. Can you help me please.

Comment: Enable remote connections in your SQL Server.

Comment: @carny666 i did it too :(

Comment: is there a reason you can't connect your .mdf file to a SQL Server instance?

Answer (score 0):

Check if SQL Server Browser service is running on your SQL server.

Comment: user2480011 its not running

Comment: I would make sure these things are running on your SQL server
- SQL Server Browser service is running
- TCP/IP protocol for the instance you want to connect to is Enabled
- Windows Firewall/any other firewall rules allow the TCP port you've configured for your specific instance.